# How to use variable from controller inside html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, meteor

I had a variable in my controller as

```
let today= new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

variable today gives the current date,which I want to set for the min-date attribute in html.

below is my html

```
 <input  class="form-control" type="datetime" date-time auto-close="true" view="date" 
min-date=              min-view="date" maxlength="10" format="dd/MM/yyyy" 
ng-model="$ctrl.DateInput" placeholder="date" required="true" >
```

How can we pass that variable value from controller to html..If I set that as min-date="2016-12-02" It is working..Now I want to get that value from the variable today....How can we do this.
Thanks.

Comment: take that `variable` in a `scope` and display in the view using `ng-model`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the value to the `$scope` object in the controller

```
$scope.today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

Or if you use `controller as syntax`, assign it to the `this` in the controller

```
this.today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

And in the `html` use

```
min-date="{{ today  }}" with $scope
min-date="{{ $ctrl.today}}" with controller
```

Comment: It is giving me reference error
angular_angular.js?hash=744f2a2…:12545 ReferenceError: today is not defined

Comment: @HVarma have you injected the `$scope`?. Create a fiddle to help us to help you )

Comment: It worked I tried this.today >it dint worked..But $scope.today worked...Thanks

Comment: @HVarma depending on the solution